# jQuery hide modal on Mouse Move

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session

I have jQuery mousemove that the function is check if session empty/no session.

Here is the jQuery code :

```
$( "html" ).mousemove(function( event ) {
               $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "ajax_no_session.php",
                data: "uid=<?php echo $uid; ?>",
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){
                    if(data == 0)
                    {
                        $(".no_interaction").modal({
                            backdrop: 'static',
                            keyboard: false
                        });
                    }
                }
                });
                return false;
            });
```

I have tried that code and successfully, if I logout using another tab then I mousemove to another tab in same url then the modal will show.

I have logout.php too that the function is to unset session.
Here is the problem. When I click `<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>` and move mouse together, the modal will show.

What I want is when I click logout.php and mousemove the mouse, do not show the modal.

Any idea?

Comment: Not clear with the requirement ..can u be more specific and explain in bit more detail..

Comment: y cant you hide the modal in logout btn click?